# Schema Choice Element Condition

Tags: xsd, schema

How can the choice keyword be manipulated to meet the following condition:

```
(Subject && MessageBody) || (Subject || MessageBody)
```

I have:

```
<xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref="Subject"/>
    <xs:element ref="MessageBody"/>
</xs:choice>
```

However Subject and MessageBody cannot co-exist in the complexType since the set enforces a XOR condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I finally came up with:

```
<xs:choice>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="engine"/>
        <xs:element ref="Type" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Type"/>
        <xs:element ref="engine" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```